# SES verification email not received

Tags: email, amazon-ses

I have a verified Domain in Amazon SES with a single email address. This address works fine and I can send and receive mails no problem.

I want to add a second email address to the domain, so I have copied the original account settings. There is a Rule Set for the new address that send to a S3 bucket and to WorkMail via an SNS topic. I can send mails from this new address. However the status is pending so I cannot reveive.

When I try to resend the verification email, the mail get sresent successfully, but I never receive the mail, neither in the S3 bucket nor in WorkMail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify the email address by logging into the email client that you used to create that email address, and then clicking on the link that you get. So if you are using Workmail as your email client, just as an example, you need to create the email address there, and then add it to your list of addresses in Amazon SES and verify it. Summarized in 3 steps:

> 1. Create an address in whatever email client you use
> 2. Go to Amazon SES and add it to your list of email address identities in Amazon SES
> 3. Send the verification email
> 4. Go back to your email client (Workmail or whatever you're using to check your emails), open verification email, and click on the link

Now your rule sets should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this doesn't fix the issue. I have created the edmail addresses in SES and configured Workmail, but nothing arrives when I send the verification mail. It's a bit frustrating

Comment: Can you describe the exact steps you're taking?

Answer (score 0):

I spend some time there... AWS has a trick there. Create AWS Work email(same you want to verify) first. Follow youtube videos-pretty easy. Then go to Amazon Ses and create email to you want to verify. The email will come to Amazon Work email. You will verify it from the web page mail application. After you need to ask Amazon to move your from Sand Box environment to Production. You will find links in SES. You fill simple form and Amazon will make it work for you. Then go back and delete Work mail or keep it(only costs 4USD per user)